# postman/newman - Updating the environmentvariables.json from github secrets

Tags: environment-variables, postman, github-actions, newman

I have a lot of environment variables in my json file. Instead of passing them as --env-var while specifying the newman run command, is it possible to update the environment variables json file directly from github secrets? Like so:

```
{
            "key": "API_ClientSecret",
            "value": "${{secrets.API_ClientSecret}}",
            "type": "default",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "API_Client_Id",
            "value": "${{secrets.API_ClientId}}",
            "type": "default",
            "enabled": true
        },
```

Comment: Nope, that's why the `--env-var` flag exists. Those would just resolve to those string values.

Comment: @DannyDainton thank you for your answer. I have quite a few environment variables and it would become tedious to specify all of them like this. Do we have any other options where I can use the environment file as is?

Comment: Not when interacting with something outside of the Collection, like you're doing. Newman doesn't know anything about GitHub so when it's interpreting the details of the Environment file, it has no idea that you're telling it to use GH Environment Variables. You could create a script and use Newman as a library https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#newmanrunevents would help with formating the command but it's basically doing the same thing.